# Accessing variable in class in Python using Google App Engine platform

Tags: python

I have a problem accessing a variable in the Post instance of a MainPage class of Google App Engine. Since I can not change the Post instance name to **init** I am not sure how to access the variable - image

```
class MainPage(Handler):
def get(self):
    dictionary = getpure()
    img = "http://www.apogeephoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/14.jpg"
    self.render("front.html", dictionary=dictionary, img = img)

def post(self):
    image = self.request.get("image")

    dictionary = getpure()

    if image == "one":
        img = "www.someaddress.jpg"
    elif image == "two":
        img = "someaddress.jpg"
    elif image == "three":
        img = "someaddress.jpg"


    self.render("front.html", dictionary=dictionary, img=img)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't link to external code (or a screenshot of your code). Edit your question to include the relevant code in text form.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions! I appreciate it.

Comment: From where exactly is it you can't access `image`?